# Multiple modals won't close if number of modal is unknown

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get the below code to work but it only seems to work for the last modal in the list.

```
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("pop-up");
var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close-modal");

for(let i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
   btns[i].onclick = function() {
      modals[i].style.display = "block";
   }

}
for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
       modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
 }
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

for(let i=0;i<modals.length;i++){
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modals[i]) {
                modals[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help clear up where I am going wrong?

EDIT: Below is a snippet using the event listening described in an answer below - this snippet shows that implementing this event listener prevents the button from working on click - am I implementing it incorrectly? If I remove the code in JS to do with clicking anywhere then the rest works.

```js
function submitBtn(){
  // Get the modal
  var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("pop-up");
  var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close-modal");

  for(let i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
    btns[i].onclick = function(){
      modals[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
    spans[i].onclick = function(){
      modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

  for(let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++){
    modals[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  });
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 10; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  display: table;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close-modal {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close-modal:hover,
.close-modal:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    stuff1<p class="close-modal">&times;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">stuff2<p class="close-modal">&times;</p></div>
</div>
<span>
  <button type="button" class="pop-up" onclick="submitBtn()">SEND</button></span>
<span>
  <button type="button" class="pop-up" onclick="submitBtn()">SEND</button></span>
```

Comment: @VXp I have added it above if that helps you find the issue

Comment: `btns[i].onclick` `spans[i].onclick` should both be replaced with the addEventListener equivalents.

Comment: I'm not getting any modals running your snippet.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath can you help provide the examples please? I am new to evenListeners and seem to be building them incorrectly

Comment: @connexo - yes the issue with the snippet is that when I add the eventListener for closing when clicking outside the modal, it prevents the button.onclick script from working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarities sake, this is the solution that I have got working:

```
    // Get the modal
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("pop-up");
var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close-modal");

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    modals[i].style.display = "block";
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    modals[i].style.display = "none";
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  modals[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (event.target == modals[i]) {
            modals[i].style.display = "none";
        }
  })
}
```

This seems to work as intended and as far as I am aware there is no issue with creating a listener for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The below is what you are looking for. As mentioned, you are overwriting the event that you've bound to `window` by looping through and recreating it, but the event only needs to be registered once, as demonstrated below.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

  for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    modals[i].style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Comment: This is probably a better approach since it creates fewer events :-)

Comment: I have implemented the above but it seems to prevent my button.onClick function from working - I have editted to add the full code

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is replacing the window.onclick listener each time, instead use `window.addEventListener('click', function....)`

You may wish to store references to these functions so you can window.removeEventListener later on.

Comment: Implementing this seems to prevent my onclick button from working - see snippet added to post in edit

Answer (score 0):

So is this close to what you're looking for?

I mostly reused your code and deleted what was in the way.

The essential part is that inside the click handler you're using to close the modals you need to check if the target of the click was one of the buttons. I also removed the spans around the buttons which seemed to not be of any meaningful use.

Lastly, I replaced your `onclick =` by `addEventListener('click',` which in contrast to onclick allows for more than one event handler for any given event.

```js
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("pop-up");

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    modals[i].style.display = "block";
  })
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button.pop-up')) return;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    modals[i].style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  display: table;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close-modal {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close-modal:hover,
.close-modal:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    stuff1
    <p class="close-modal">&times;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">stuff2
    <p class="close-modal">&times;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="pop-up">SEND</button>
<button type="button" class="pop-up">SEND</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it seems to not work if I include `  for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    modals[i].style.display = "none";
  }` and I am not sure why. Also where here does it state what to do when the "close-modal" itself is clicked?

Comment: The close modal click is handled by the one closing handler.

Comment: @JDT Is your question answered?

Comment: yes, the solution I used was the one I posted above